# Positioning an image in the centre?

Tags: html

I am struggling to position an image that I am using as the background as auto. I also have an article tag that will not centre.

How do I fix the issue with the following code?

```
body {
    background:url('index1.jpg')no-repeat;
    width:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
body {
    background: url('index1.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This should center your background image and resize it accordingly. Hope this helps.

**EDIT (Pertaining to your comment):**

First off, in order to obtain a border on an element you use the `border`, not `border-radius`. `border-radius` will round the edges of an element rather than add a border itself.

In order to center objects you need to use `margin: auto;`. This will place the content in the center of its parent container.

Here is a fiddle of the working code: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MitulP91/3WbAv/1/)

In the future please attempt to do a little research and figure things out on your own. All of these solutions could be found on existing questions on SO.

Comment: how do i move this to the centre  


article{
background:white;
width:600px;
height:300px;
border-radius:7px solid;

 
}

Comment: Edited to include centered article.